# H2Database:MODE=PostgreSQL: doesn't support ENUM type

Tags: java, postgresql, scala, jdbc, h2

I want to use H2 with PostgreSQL dialect.

My H2 version:

```
"com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.4.190"
```

This is my config H2:

```
jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=PostgreSQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
jdbc.driver_class=org.h2.Driver
jdbc.username=sa
jdbc.password=""
```

This is my SQL-statement:

```
create type myEnum as enum ('one', 'two', 'three');
```

When I try to execute it (with simple scala-JDBC), the following exception is thrown:

```
Unknown data type: "ENUM"; SQL statement:
```

From official site http://www.h2database.com/html/roadmap.html?highlight=enum&search=enum#firstFound:

```
Support ENUM data type (see MySQL, PostgreSQL, MS SQL Server, maybe others).
```

Can anybody tell me what I do wrong?

Comment: Nothing, wrong. This is simply not yet implemented, your link is the _roadmap_ so it lists *planned* features. Why do you need that? Why don't you just use a real Postgres server?

Comment: I use real PostgreSQL server for web-application, and I want to use H2-in-memory database for unit-tests.

Comment: It is not a good idea to use a different DBMS for testing. Apart from the obvious syntax differences (and feature gap) there are also subtle differences in the behaviour which essentially make your tests void when not run against the real DBMS.

Comment: This answer might be helpful: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48955100/error-when-setting-up-h2-database/64044332#64044332