# How to run H2 database engine in PostgreSQL mode?

Tags: java, postgresql, h2, in-memory-database

**Anti-Objective**:
I know that it is frowned upon to use another database while testing. I'm not here for the argument of what to use and when.

**Objective**:
How to setup and use H2 in Postgres mode. I have tried to run the jar file of H2 and the H2 web console is probably connecting to actual Postgres server when using `Generic PostgreSQL` profile.(I don't know how to verify it | I am rookie in Database administration) I want to run H2 and run a SQL script I have, on it. No in embedded mode but as a server.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33825735/h2databasemode-postgresql-doesnt-support-enum-type